# Uniform convergence of series of functions given convergence of coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

Prove that if $\sum{a_n}$ converges then the series $\sum{a_nx^n}$ converges uniformly on [0,1]

I believe that I must use the Weierstrass M-test to show this convergence, but this requires that the series be non-negative. I'm not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 1):

One form of [Abel's theorem](https://books.google.ca/books?id=L25yJhCll78C&pg=PA453&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) states that if a power series converges at end-point $R$ of its interval of convergence, then it converges uniformly on $[0,R]$.

But if this was supposed to be an easy exercise in elementary real analysis, I suspect the intention was to have $\sum_n a_n$ converge absolutely, or maybe $a_n \ge 0$.